# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module for sample file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a folder for test only that contain only 3 file

- index.js
- sample.js
- index.html

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import { data } from './sample';
console.log(data)
const newObj = Object.entries(sampleOb).filter((item, index) => index === 0)
console.log(Object.fromEntries(newObj) )
```

sample.js

```
export const data = {
    name:"abc",
    age:"19"
}
```

But problem is when i try to import data.js to index.js, it show this error
[image]
So how to fix this, thank you

Comment: Not a major issue in this case, but posting this for awareness of when to use images in questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: hint: `script` can have a `module` type

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `index.js` is declared as a script but not as one which is a module. You can learn more about declaring a script as a module from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html).

Your code would be more correct as:

```html
<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: not working to me, throw other error